# Как обрезать строку до заданного количества символов

Tags: java, android

Есть переменная `String mawa;`, в которой хранится некий текст.

Как сделать так, чтобы этот текст обрезался до 25 символов?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
mawa = mawa.substring(startindex, endindex);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Answer (score 16):

В предыдущих ответах не упомянуто, что будет, если исходная строка короче 25 символов. Если такая ситуация возможна, её следует обработать отдельно. Например:

```
int limit = 25;
String subStr = mawa.length() > limit ? mawa.substring(0, limit) : mawa;
```

Также не упомянуто, что будет, если строка содержит суррогатные пары [UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Предположим, ваши пользователи — мормоны-фундаменталисты и общаются с помощью [Дезеретского алфавита](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82):

```
String mawa = "";
```

Попробуем сделать наивным способом:

```
String subStr = mawa.substring(0, 25);
System.out.println(subStr);
```

В результате видим:

```
?
```

Символов всего 12 и вопросик ещё в конце появился странный. Определённо такая программа не проявляет должного уважения к мормонам-фундаменталистам. Чтобы всё работало правильно, надо, например, так:

```
int limit = 25;
String subStr = mawa.codePointCount(0, mawa.length()) > limit ? 
        mawa.substring(0, mawa.offsetByCodePoints(0, limit)) : mawa;
System.out.println(subStr);
```

Тогда мы видим действительно 25 символов:

Вам всё ещё кажется, что взять подстроку от строки просто?

Answer (score 12):

```
mawa.substring(0,25);
```

Метод `substring()` используется для извлечения подстроки из объекта `String`. Этот метод создает новую копию символов из того диапазона индексов оригинальной строки, который вы указали при вызове.
Можно указать только индекс первого символа нужной подстроки — тогда будут скопированы все символы, начиная с указанного и до конца строки. Также можно указать и начальный, и конечный индексы — при этом в новую строку будут скопированы все символы, начиная с первого ука­занного, и до (но не включая его) символа, заданного конечным индек­сом.

```
"Hello World".substring(6) -> "World" 

"Hello World".substring(3,8) -> "lo Wo"
```